# Google preferences are invalid and Google 3 bars are only 3 dots in upper right browser

Tags: plugins

I was doing emails on Yahoo just fine for a couple of hours, crossing back and forth between there and Facebook and around 6:30ish p.m. I tried to get on Farmville and the plugin message popped up "couldn't load plugin" then I looked up in the upper right corner and my Google 3 bars are just 3 dots now.  I redownloaded Google Chrome, powered off and back on and it's the same.  HELP!

Google preferences are invalid and Google 3 bars are only 3 dots in upper right browser! Help!  Game plugins won't load!
bplunkett1@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your Google Chrome. It is a new Chrome version 53.0.2785 what was introduced between 2016-08-31 and 2016-09-07. One of the changes includes -

> New browser's inside look, including a new bookmark

If you are interested why Google Chrome have chosen to change its icons I recommend reading this [Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Google-choose-to-use-vertical-three-dots-icon-instead-of-Hamburger-icon-on-Chrome) as well as this [Google Chrome Help Forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TfCIsMvQTXY).